# Parse PNG string into Ruby file

Tags: ruby

How do I parse a PNG in string format (like below) into a file in Ruby?

```
\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01,\x00\x00\
```

Adding more details I left in the comments.

If the PNG existed on the file system, I could open the file with File.open. I want the same object File.open would create, but I need to create it from the string, not the file system.

Ultimately, I want to assign this to a Paperclip attachment and have it recognize the object as a png.

Comment: Parse? Into a file? What did you mean by that?

Comment: If the PNG existed on the file system, I could open the file with File.open.  I want the same object File.open would create, but I need to create it from the string, not the file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File` is just an implementation of `IO`. Ruby has another `IO` implementation that can read/write strings called, obviously, [`StringIO`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html).

```
file = StringIO.new("\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01,\x00\x00\")
```

Your comment suggests you need this to work with `paperclip`. In that case paperclip will usually (depends on version) want a file name and mime type, so add them before assigning the file to your paperclip attachment attribute.

```
file.content_type = "image/png"
file.original_filename = "image.png"
object.attachment = file
```

The above works for the most recent paperclip. Still better than writing to a temp file.

Comment: Obviously? It's only obvious in the hindsight. :)

Comment: Agreed, this is better than tempfile :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [StringIO](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html):

```
s = "\x89PNG\r\n..."
file = StringIO.new(s)
```

Alternatively, you can use [Tempfile](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) (if you want *real* file object):

```
require 'tempfile'

file = Tempfile.new('png')
file.write "\x89PNG\r\n..."
file.rewind # move position pointer to the beginning of the file
```

Comment: When I set a paperclip attachment with this method, it's saving as a text file, but rendering as an image.  Maybe it's just paperclip assuming it's a text file b/c it's a StringIO object.

Comment: Well, you're saving a string. Did you expect paperclip to read your mind? Anyway, it's out of scope here. Feel free to ask another question.

Comment: Pretty sure I didn't expect it to read mind.  The behavior I wanted was the same behavior as if I opened a png file from disk so I'm fairly certain it's within scope. If I had opened a png from disk, it wouldn't be a string would it?

Comment: You asked about how to get IO-like object from a string. And now, I think, you are asking "how do I make paperclip recognize that this string is, in fact, PNG file"? This is another question.

Comment: You can take Paperclip out of the requirements and you get the same question. I want the same object as File.open'ing a png from the file system.  Your solution does not do that.

Comment: @ckarbass My answer shows how to use `StringIO` with `paperclip`.